# Scrapy Not fetching data on Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am new to scrapy I tried to get the name of reviewer in below urls.

Url 1 :  http://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurant_Review-g34515-d3785272-Reviews-Kings_Orlando-Orlando_Florida.html

Url 2:   http://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurant_Review-g34515-d3785272-Reviews-or220-Kings_Orlando-Orlando_Florida.html

I fetch URL1 from scrapy shell

then I run

```
sel.xpath('//div[@class="username mo"]/span/text()').extract()
```

or

```
hxs.select('//div[@class="username mo"]/span/text()').extract()
```

I get this which is was I expected.

> [u'1TrippyTraveler', u'Amanda G', u'Christina B', u'Jason B', u'mitch c', u'Kim H', u'lakepointeman', u'JPawlak84', u'Rik W', u'Ashton L', u'Kayla V', u'OllieEdmunds', u'rinna40', u'rinna40']

But I run the same thing for URL 2.

I get

> [u'Kayla V', u'OllieEdmunds', u'rinna40', u'rinna40']

But the expected output is

> [u'Edmar J', u'Helena T', u'Viviane00', u'GracaSabi', u'Marlise', u'Beatriz21', u'anapemost',  u'Kayla V', u'OllieEdmunds', u'rinna40', u'rinna40']

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: search for "javascript rendering"

Comment: I didn't have Idea on that Could you please share your answer to me

Comment: the reviews on that page are being loaded dynamically, you need to find out which request is actually loading that information, or use a something like `selenium` to load a page like a browser.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but the URL 1 is working fine and URL 2 is not working

Comment: then you should contact the website to make both work as you want.